# Запрос в SQL вывода суммы оставшегося товара

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, select

Здравствуйте. Я пока начинающий в SQL, пожалуйста не ругать. 
Дано задание :

```
product | action |   date   | amount
book    |   1    | 1/5/2017 |  100
book    |  -1    | 3/6/2017 |   30
```

`1`- ввод товара, `amount` - количество,
`-1` - вывод товара

Вопрос следующий: Вывести таблицу в виде до определенной даты

```
product | income | outcome | sum
```

где `sum` - это количество оставшегося товара

Comment: @Mike дак сумму отрицательных, положительных, и общую видимо

Comment: Что вы уже пытались сделать ? вообще вам нужен where который ограничит дату на требуемую, group by product, и суммы вроде `sum(case when action < 0 then amount end)` ну и последняя сумма просто `sum(amount * action)`

Comment: Покажите желаемый вывод на показанных данных, а не только шапку. *Вывести таблицу в виде до определенной даты* Вот про эту дату - подробнее. Откуда берётся?

Comment: sum(case when action < 0 then amount end) ну и последняя сумма просто sum(amount * action) Спасибо. case when помог @Mike

Comment: А есть ли решение без case when? с помощью формулы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select product
, date -- дата
,sum(case when action = 1 then action else 0 end act) income --сколько пришло
,sum(case when action = -1 then action else 0 end act2) outcome --сколько ушло
,sum(action) sumaction -- разница между пришло/ушло
, (amount + sumaction) sum --кол-во оставшегося товара
from table_name --название таблицы
where date between to_date('01.01.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') and 
to_date('02.01.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') -- условие на дату
Group by product, data, income, outcome
```

Должно работать, по идее.

Если action может быть любым отрицалельным/положительным числом, то условие для income и outcome нужно изменить на

```
,sum(case when action > 0 then action else 0 end act) income --сколько 
пришло
,sum(case when action < 0 then action else 0 end act2) outcome --сколько 
ушло
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло! Благодарю

Comment: А есть ли решение без case when? с помощью формулы

Comment: Нет. Case(when-then-else) - это замена (If - then-else)
Без этого не будет счетчика income-outcome
Есть такая функция как sign(), если > 0 то вставляет 1, если <0 то вставляет -1, если 0 то 0
Она является только счетчиком (в вашем случае) на положительные/отрицательные транзакции. В вашем случае это не подходит.